# How to measure the RF output power of the PCB board?

Tags: pcb, rf, power-amplifier

I have designed a PCB board, having a RF power amplifier with an output power of  34dBm and two voltage regulators giving output voltage of 2.7V and 3.5V respectively which will be the input to power amplifier.
How to measure the output power of this PCB board after assembling the components?  or  Is it possible to measure the output power before assembling ?

Comment: What's the designed output impedance of this amplifier?  Does it use an output transformer?  Your numbers are a bit suspect.  As to your actual question, you would connect a resistive dummy load and measure the RF voltage.  Ordinarily you could use a power meter or some sufficiently rated attenuators feeding a calibrated receiver such as a spectrum analyzer, but if your numbers are correct you'll first need to get to a standard impedance before you can use everyday instruments.

Comment: The Amplifier is said to have an output impedance of 50ohms and no output transformer is being used.  Can't I directly measure the power using the RMS voltage and RMS current values ?

Comment: Then your numbers are wrong.  Calculate it for yourself - what is the RF voltage for 34 dBm across 50 ohms?   Where is that going to come from???

Comment: The voltages are the DC inputs to the power amplifier, the actual  RF input signal has 14dBm power at 868MHz frequency.

Comment: Again, what is the RF voltage for your designed output of 34 dBm across 50 ohms? Where is that voltage going to come from???

Comment: @Chris Stratton while unlikely the amplifier could be built with multiple parallel stages and internal matching to 50 ohms, and an internal impedance less than 50ohm.

Comment: You measure the output power with a calibrated receiver, for instance a power meter, spectrum analyser or some other thing that can measure relaibly at 868MHz (not a job for a DMM, or even a fast scope). Put up a schematic of the amplifier, to quell this discussion about whether it's a distributed or transformed output, 34dBm is 2.5watts, which needs more than 11v rms into 50ohms. At the moment, it's not obvious that a 3.5v rail could deliver that. At that power, you could build yourself a thermal RF substituion power meter!

Answer (score 1):

The most correct way to measure RF power is with an RF power meter. These come in various shapes and sizes from vendors like Keysight, Rohde & Schwaz, etc.
The tricky part here is that you might not have a clean, intended output point to measure from (if your antenna is integrated on the same PCB).

These devices need to be calibrated in order to make the measurement.

Alternatively, you can use a device like a spectrum analyzer to measure the output power. This will however not give you quite the same accuracy, and can also not be calibrated as easily to take into account cable losses. However, at 800-something MHz that you are working at, cable losses will not be too significant (it all depends on quite how accurate you need to measure this).

If you need to measure the power while the device is running, you can use power meter IC's. These are common as they are used for RSSI measurements, gain control, etc. Some out there are able to measure to sub-0.1 dB accuracy.